# Not understanding velocity addition (or substraction maybe) in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, velocity

Suppose there is a train that has a velocity of $v=0.6c$. It travels $L_0$ distance in $T_0$ time. They are measured by a person sitting on a bench beside the track. So from train's perspective distance should be $L=L_0 (1-v^2/c^2)$ and time should be $T=T_0/(1-v^2/c^2)$ so should't a passenger think the train is moving with velocity, $V=L/T$ where $V<V_0$. Can you please explain this from Einstein velocity addition perspective?

Comment: I think there is a mistake in the question.  The Lorentz factors should probably be square rooted, $\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose train's and track's clocks are set to zero when the first wagon passes by the bench. The clocks of the wagons are syncronized in the train's frame.

In the time $T_0$, according to the bench clock, the clock in the wagon, that is now passing by, is:
$$T = T_0\frac{1} {\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$
As the train has velocity $v$, the length from the first wagon to this one is $L_0 = vT_0$ for the bench frame.

The same distance to the first wagon, measured by the train is greater, because it is measured at its own frame. And the formula for length contraction is from the stationary to the moving frame, in this case from the train to the track:
$$L_0 = L \sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}$$
So, the velocities are $v$ for both frames.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, in special relativity we can't talk about absolute *velocity* or how far it *travels* in some amount of *time*, because all of these quantities depend on the frame we're measuring from. You must always be careful to specify who is measuring these quantities. In this case, it's implied that the passenger is measuring these quantities.

I think you may have a misconception about what time dilation and length contraction means. I like to think that if the person on the platform watches someone holding a clock on the train, they'll see the clock tick slower. Furthermore, if the person on the train is holding a ruler along the axis of relative motion, the person on the platform will measure that the train's ruler is shorter. But if the person on the platform measures the *speed* of the train, they're measuring with respect to *their own* reference frame, so the speed is still $0.6c$.

The velocity addition won't appear here: there's only one relative velocity we're interested in: the train relative to the observer. Velocity addition in SR appears if someone on the train throws a ball at $0.5c$ relative to the train, and we ask what speed the person on the platform measures the ball at. If the passenger throws the ball in the same direction as the train is moving, from the perspective of the person on the platform, then clearly it can't be moving at $0.5c+0.6c = 1.1c$, instead via a process like the one you describe we can derive the velocity addition formula and find the speed the person on the platform measures is $(0.5c+0.6c)/(1+0.5c\times0.6c/c^2) = \frac{11}{13}c$.

I suppose we could calculate (somewhat trivially) the velocity of the train relative to the person on the platform via the velocity addition formula. If the person on the train throws a ball at a speed $v$ in her reference frame such that the ball appears stationary to the person on the platform, then we can calculate what $v$ must be in the train's frame of reference. That is, using the velocity addition formula, we know $0.6c$--the speed of the train--and $v$ must add together to get 0. Classically, this means $v = -0.6c$, and we can see that this holds in SR too: if $ 0 =(0.6c + v)/(1+(0.6c)\times v/c^2)$, then since the denominator is not zero we can cancel it off and find $0 = 0.6c +v$ and thus $v = -0.6c$.